Calculator made from scratch
See, I know it might be a dumb question, but I would like an answer, however dumb it might be.
I never did any electronics before. However, I had an idea in mind that even if I can't do it right now I would want to do some day.
A calculator with updatable firmware, small internal storage and an ability for having like 3 programs you could select and each would have a different function.
Now, this is no easy task and I know that. So I wanted to know what should I learn, read and watch in order to do something like that? I know displays, buttons and many other things are needed. For the record I can code in C and alike so that I have done, I just would want to know the "hardware" side of things, because software I could probably handle fine, although I do not know how to code for such a device.
Cheers!

You might be better off at RetroComputing. They build computers from TTL and 'scratchier' things. You need to specify what exactly your building blocks are going to be- MCUs, TTL, transistors, sand?

I dont know which is why I need to learn everything up and need resources for learning, although most likely transistors

Start with some Arduino educational resources to simply program a calculator. Find some tutorials about the components that such an MCU is built with internally, CPU, RAM, Flash etc. Keep digging down into how those components are made until you are happy with the level. Then use those components to build back up again. The RetroComputing board does this all the time, and is populated by people who enjoy doing this, and helping others to do it.

I'd suggest you get something like this so you can get the hang of writing embedded software on a bit of working hardware. Then you can start learning about putting your own hardware together if you want to.

@Melody although you mention transistors, it is better if you focus on the higher level, first. I suggest you get a book called "Bebop Bytes Back: An Unconventional Guide to Computers" by Clive Maxfield. He covers exactly what you are asking about. A calculator! Best wishes.

Study Arduino and example projects.
If you can code in C and can learn the protocols for communication with a small display and an appropriate key pad (possibly over a serial bus) it would not be hard to program an Arduino to create a calculator.
A starting point would be to write a C program to turn your PC into a calculator.
The details of reading in updated would also be easy if it could be updated by connection to a PC.
